# Add Zoom In/Out on Single Click Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Is there a way to add gallery like feature to owl. I mean I want to zoom in/out slide on click and also on zoom in grab/drag the zoomed area.
I tried it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items : 10
  });

  $('.link').on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
      $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
    } else{
      $this.css('background','#7fc242').addClass('clicked');
    }
  });

});
```

Slide zooms but on drag owl's main drag function runs and move to next slide. I want owl to work like [PhotoSwipe](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe) does.
The only issue with PhotoSwipe is that it opens in fullscreen lightbox view. I also tried [zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) on click but it don't support dragging.

Can anyone guide me how to add these functionalities?

Comment: why not combine this 2 libraries?

Comment: guide me kindly because i tried but its not working